# Parentheses change O(n) algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stack, dynamic-programming

If I have a `n` length string of open `(` and close `)` parentheses and I have to count the number of time I change the close `)` parentheses to open `(` every time when I have more close parentheses than the open one at the current moment while traversing from left to right in every substring of that string.

For e.g. : n = 3, s = `) ( )` :

all substring of s will be `[ ), ) (, ) ( ), (, ( ), ) ]`

we will have to count in all substring, like in `) ( )` we have close = 1 and open = 0, close > open hence count++. Now the currently processed string is `( ( )`, and have no more change to do. Similarly, when we do this for all substring count will be 4.

I wrote a brute force code. I'm assuming is there any way to do this using stack or dynamic programming to do in O(n) or something?

My brute force is like : 
1. Create every substring of the given string. O(n^2). 
2. Iterating through one substring at a time to count the change. O(n) 
Hence, total complexity is O(n^3)

Comment: *describing* what you do is nice, but it is not exact. Please provide code or pseudo code of your brute force algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The O annotation is not taking into account things like your bookkeeping/state variables etc. It is only related to how often the input data has to be processed.
If I understood your task right, you just need to loop a single time through every character.
Since during that single loop there is no information available to you that tells you something about characters further down the line, you have absolutely no choice than to loop through the entire string a single time.
Therefore O(N) is the best possible complexity for this task.

If your "bruteforce code" loops more than once (aka is not O(N)), post it here and people will look.

Comment: `It is only related to how often the input data has to be processed` that's not entirely true. Big-O notation describes the relationship between complexity and number of elements - always in the worst case. If you have `O(1)` (constant time), the algorithm has the same complexity with 0, 1, or 10000000 elements. If it's `O(n)` complexity, then the algorithm is twice as complex with 100 elements than it is with 50 elements.

Comment: His English is a bit broken, but I'm pretty sure that he's saying that he needs the sum of the results og your O(n) algorithm, performed for each possible substring of the original string.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED Doesn't this complexity derive from how often the data is processed? Like when you have an algorithm that has to "process" (access) each element once for each element (aka a nested loop), you have complexity O(n*n). @ DeducibleSteak Hm, possibly.. Needs some clarification.

Comment: I have to do the process you said for every substring of the given string, not just the given string itself. 
My brute force is like :
1. Create every substring of the given string. O(n^2).
2. Iterating through one substring at a time to count the change. O(n)
Hence, total complexity is O(n^3)

Comment: @DragonGamer, for an introduction to algorithms and complexity, I recommend ... the Introduction to Algorithms: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844 In short, how many times you access the data does not matter, how much work you do, does.

Comment: @DragonGamer That's a common way it's explained but that isn't the _real_ relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in O(n^2) by doing some precomputation. Take two arrays left and right of size n(string length). left[index] will store no of left parentheis from s[0] to s[index], similarly right will store no of right parenthesis. So for your example `s = ")()"`, left will be [0, 1, 1] and right will be [1, 1, 2]. This precomputation can be done in O(n). Now we need to figure out how many left parenthesis should have been added for each interval (i,j). So for each interval and sum them up. For each interval figure out this value using the precomputed array in O(1). To iterate each interval we need O(n^2). So the overall complexity is O(n^2).

```
int main(){
    vector<int>prefix_sum_left_parentheisis(1000, 0);
    vector<int>prefix_sum_right_parentheisis(1000, 0);
    string s = ")()";
    int count_left_parenthesis = 0;
    int count_right_parenthesis = 0;

    int index = 0;
    for(auto ch:s) {
        if(ch=='(')
            count_left_parenthesis++;
        else
            count_right_parenthesis++;

        prefix_sum_left_parentheisis[index] = count_left_parenthesis;
        prefix_sum_right_parentheisis[index] = count_right_parenthesis;
        index++;
    }

    auto total = 0;
    for(auto i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        for(auto j = i; j < s.size(); j++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                total += max(0, prefix_sum_right_parentheisis[j] - prefix_sum_left_parentheisis[j]);
            }
            else {
                auto count_left_parenthesis_in_range = prefix_sum_left_parentheisis[j] - prefix_sum_left_parentheisis[i-1];
                auto count_right_parenthesis_in_range = prefix_sum_right_parentheisis[j] - prefix_sum_right_parentheisis[i-1];
                total += max(0,count_right_parenthesis_in_range - count_left_parenthesis_in_range);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "answer is: " << total;
}
```